# javascript password input validate launch modal

Tags: javascript

i am trying to check if two (password) inputfields are the same. If not than the modal should launch.
I can't get this to work. Can someone advise me for a solution or tell me what i am doing wrong.
Thnx.

```js
function checkEmail(theForm) {
 if (theForm.EMAIL_1.value != theForm.EMAIL_2.value)
  {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="modal.php" onsubmit="return checkEmail(this);" id="lop">
<p> Enter Your Email Address:<br>
<input type="TEXT" name="EMAIL_1" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
<br>
Please Confirm Your Email Address:
<br>
<input type="TEXT" name="EMAIL_2" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
<br>
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Send Address!"></p> 
</form>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header alert-danger">
        <h5 class="modal-title w-100  text-center" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Error</h5>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-danger text-center">Password does not match</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
 dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser's console and can you please provide us the value of the `theForm` variable?

Comment: Try console.log(theForm.EMAIL_1.value) and console.log(theForm.EMAIL_2.value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to stop the form from submitting if you want javascript to do the input checking.

```
function checkEmail(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 const theForm = e.currentTarget;
 if (theForm.EMAIL_1.value != theForm.EMAIL_2.value)
  {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
   return true;
  }
  theForm.submit(); // same password
}
```

then pass the event into the js function:

```
<form action="modal.php" onsubmit="return checkEmail(event);" id="lop">
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem with a php script:

```
<?php



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if ($password != $password2) {
        echo "<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });
</script>";
    }
}

?>
```